# I just moved my HD from a Lenovo X201 to a Lenovo W520, and everything seems to work. Is this OK?

Tags: installation, boot

I had Ubuntu Natty full configured and working on the SSD drive in my Lenovo X201 Thinkpad.

Then I got a Lenovo W520 Thinkpad, which I'm sure has different wireless card and graphics card and other things.

I popped out the SSD drive from the X201 and put it into the W520. This SSD is the master/boot drive and also holds all my data. I turned on the W520, and to my surprise, everything just works. Is this to be expected? I don't need to do a clean installation?

In other words, is Ubuntu generally installed on a hard drive in a way that make it portable across different Thinkpad models and configurations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is the normal outcome. You usually can move a hard disk from one system to another and expect it to work.

There are some exceptions, like when you are using some proprietary RAID controller or you have tweaked something important that results in an incompatibility. But these are the exception not the rule.

Comment: Wow, this is so convenient. I wonder if the same applies to OS X volumes.